# Does the Wizard's Electrocute gain the effects of Prodigy for every monster hit in the chain?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Wizard's signature spell [Electrocute](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/electrocute) reads

> Lightning arcs from your fingertips, dealing 80% weapon damage as
>   Lightning. The lightning can jump, hitting up to 2 additional enemies.

I use it with the Chain Lightening rune which increases the number of enemies I can hit to 6.

Does each enemy I hit in the chain give me 4 Arcane Power with [Prodigy](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/prodigy)? Meaning I can get at maximum 24 arcane power with one cast of Electrocute? Or does Prodigy only proc once per Electrocute cast?

Prodigy reads:

> When you deal damage with a Signature spell, you gain 4 Arcane Power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electrocute's chain hits will count as regular kills for the massacre bonus so it's very likely that they'll also count for the arcane bonus.

The intresting thing is that [electrocute](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/electrocute) is a channeling spell so you can keep electrocuting for additional damage, hence more arcane power. I will try it out asaply and come back when I know for sure.

EDIT: Yes, you are right. Every additional hit will generate arcane power through [prodigy](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/prodigy).