# Will Split trigger Prodigy for each Magic Missile fired?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

On a similar vein as [this question about Electrocute](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70642/does-the-wizards-electrocute-gain-the-effects-of-prodigy-for-every-monster-hit), will the three [Magic Missiles fired by the Split rune](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/magic-missile) trigger the effects of [Prodigy](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/prodigy) for each of the missiles that hits an enemy, or only once per cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing it does appear that multiple hits by using the 'Split' rune will trigger multiple effects from the 'Prodigy' passive ability. With this in mind in conjunction with the thread you've linked for Electrocute, I believe it safe to state that the 'Prodigy' passive will proc every single time one of the signature abilities hits. This should mean that the 'Spectral Blades' ability is overpowered for Arcane Power regeneration.

After some further testing with Spectral Blades I can confirm this is actually how the 'Prodigy' passive works (one attack with Spectral Blades on a group of 7 enemies resulted in my Arcane Power going from 'nearly empty' to 'nearly full' in one attack).

**My methodology for testing**:

- Act 1 inferno, first quest
- Arcane Orb as my secondary attack
- Prodigy active as one of my passives
- Magic Missiles + Split rune as my primary attack in the first pass
- Run out past Rumford at the gate into Old Tristram Road, you'll meet a pack of 6-8 mobs
- Empty Arcane Power using Arcane Orb
- Attack the group
- Observe results

**What I found**:

- Magic Missiles without the Split rune will provide less Arcane Power than with the Split rune
- Spectral Blades on a large group will provide Arcane Power back for every enemy that is hit
- Electrocute will provide Arcane Power for targets hit by the chained element of the attack

**Conclusion**:

The 'Prodigy' passive ability does **exactly what it says it does**. When you deal damage with a Signature ability with the 'Prodigy' passive enabled, you will get 4 Arcane Power *per enemy that is damaged during that cast*.

This stacks with the equivalent runes on the abilities themselves, so you can use Prodigy + Siphoning Blades, for example.

Comment: Excellent answer! I was going to test this out this week, but you've saved me the trouble.

Comment: Great work! Does this also mean that if I'm facing a single enemy and two of my Split missiles hit it, I'll only gain the AP bonus once?

Comment: I don't know - that would be worth a test, it certainly works in the scenario that they hit different enemies and based on the tooltip I would assume yes but I'll confirm.

Comment: After some testing it appears that each missile will trigger the effect of the Prodigy passive if it hits an enemy - regardless of whether it is the same enemy or several.